How to remove arbitrary number of spaces at the beginning of indented line in Xcode?
I have a code like this one:
if (a == b) {
    line 1
        line 2
    line 3
        line 4
        line 5
    line 6
}

The cursor is at the beginning of line 2 and Xcode is configured to indent using spaces, not tabs. If I press the Delete key at the beginning of line 2, it will delete 4 spaces, not one. And I need to reduce the indentation of line 2 from 8 spaces to 6. How can I do this?
